# Android Architecture navigation Component with Bottom Navigation?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-bottomnav, android-bottom-nav-view

Now I am wondering which is the most proper way of implementation when want to combine `BottomNavigation` with the new `Android Architecture Navigation Component`?

For now found two approaches:

1. Single Navigation Graph which maintains all `BottomNavigation` items and which is shown here from `Google Codelabs`: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#1
2. Multiple Navigation Graphs where every `BottomNavigation` item has its own `navigation graph` which maintains only its behavior and `backstack` which i shown here: https://proandroiddev.com/mastering-the-bottom-navigation-with-the-new-navigation-architecture-component-cd6a71b266ae

My opinion is that the second one is more clear and understandable, but maybe you have another opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Having separate backstacks or not is a decision based on user experience but if you do want multiple backstacks for bottomnavigation then follow the link for correct approach by androidx developers.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends with the number of nested fragments you will have per each navigation item. The fewer the fragments then i would use the first approach and the more the fragments then i would use the latter approach